# On gitlab permissions

Tags: gitlab

A project was created on gitlab with the default branch master, which is now set to protect the branch, and merge and push can only be done by the master programmer.An ordinary user is then created, dragged into the project, and set up to be a developer.This developer pulled the master code, and after modification, he could directly push it to gitlab warehouse, which was not right. What I thought was that he could not operate the master, but in fact he was not limited, may I ask what was wrong

Answer (score 1):

A [GitLab protected branch](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html) prevents pushes from everybody except users with Maintainer permission.

Double-check:

- the rights associated with that project master branch
  [image: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/img/protected_branches_devs_can_push.png]
- the rights associated with that user (is he/she an admin of the GitLab remote instance? In that case, even declared as a developer, he/she could still push to a protected branch)
- the actual push (does it resulted in a merge request?)

Comment: The newly created account is not an admin of the GitLab remote instance,but he still can push to the protected branch.The developer has made some changes on the master

Comment: @baiytree Is your GitLab remote instance an Enterprise Edition one?

Comment: My gitlab is Community edition.Doesn't the community version have this feature?

Comment: @baiytree yes, but not complete, as mentioned in https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/user/project/protected_branches.html: "Additional functionality for GitLab Enterprise Edition: Restrict push and merge access to certain users"